# How to get index of nested row in antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd's nested table. I want to get the contents of the row clicked, which is already nested within. How can i go about it?

With expandedrowrender's record property, I get all the rows within that particular section. So it was of no use.

I am passing the record to a function that renders each row within.

```
renderContentTable = (record, index, indent, expanded) => {
    columns = this.renderBannerTable(record);
}
```

What i want is this, when any of there rows are clicked, I want to get the contents of that particular row. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the onRow table prop, see [docs](https://ant.design/components/table/#onRow-usage). You should be able to access row's data by using the `event` property.

```
<Table
  onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
     return {
        onClick: event => {/* Your code here*/}
     }
  }
// ...
</Table>
```

Comment: I actually have a button placed in each column. When that button is pressed, then I want the row information. How can I use onRow() when only that button is pressesd?

Comment: and can i call two functions inside onRow()? Because I am using onRow() for drag-drop.